# How to list all email IDs who have sent a mail to you on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, email

On Mac, How do we get the list of email ID's who have personally sent an email to me over the course of years by using the local copy of emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac stores the email files as .emlx files. Usually it's present under `/Users/<username>/Library/Mail/`.
We could parse these files using [emlx](https://pypi.org/project/emlx/) python library. For every email message object, we could parse the email's header to filter

- mails that has your name on the TO field
- ignore few senders who are known to be bots or departments.

```py
import glob

import emlx

count = 0
# list of keywords which denotes the emails that we don't want; mostly from bots and departments
from_exclusion_list = ["reply", "replies", "support", "mailer"]
# to store the list of email ids
senders_set = set()
# path of the mbox folder
mbox_path = "/Users/<username>/Library/Mail/"
glob_extension = "/**/*.emlx"
my_mail = "a@example.com"

for filepath in glob.iglob(mbox_path + glob_extension, recursive=True):
    count += 1
    # print(filepath)
    try:
        m = emlx.read(filepath)
    except:
        # ignore corrupt mail files
        continue
    h: dict = m.headers
    if not h.__contains__('To'):
        continue
    to: str = str(h['To']).lower()
    # 1. filter messages sent personally to me
    if to.__contains__(my_mail):
        fromA: str = str(h['From']).lower()
        # 2. filter mails from automated and dls
        if not any(fromExclude in fromA for fromExclude in from_exclusion_list):
            senders_set.add(fromA)

print("Parsed emails: ", count)
print("Sender's: ", senders_set)
```